# AngularJS: Truncate multi-line HTML bound in ng-repeat/ng-bind-html

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, truncate, ellipsis

I have following ng-repeat

```
<div class="item-post" ng-repeat="item in items">
    <div class="item-content" ng-bind-html="item.text"></div>
</div>
```

where item.text is multi-line HTML text and it displays correctly, but I need to truncate it to max-height of item-post div (250px). And then append three dots signalizing that text is longer.

I wanted to use [jquery.autoellipsis](http://pvdspek.github.io/jquery.autoellipsis/) which is working for example on `div` with static content.

For AngularJS I have found [angular-ellipsis](https://github.com/dibari/angular-ellipsis), but is doesn't work with HTML, only plain text. I need to achieve it on HTML content.

Thanks in advance for help!

**EDIT/SOLUTION:**

Finally I have been able to use jquery.autoellipsis plugin using custom directive (based on asgoth's answer):

```
myDirectives.directive('htmlEllipsis', ['$timeout', function($timeout) {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
                $timeout(function() {
                    angular.element(element).ellipsis();
                }, 0);

            }
        };
    }]);
```

And in partial view:

```
<div class="item-post" ng-repeat="item in items">
    <div class="item-content" ng-bind-html="item.text" html-ellipsis></div>
</div>
```

**EDIT2:**

Directive from asgoth's answer after his edit works well, using another approach than above-mentioned directive.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I were you I would make a directive to use the jquery plugin (jquery.autoellipsis):

```
angular.module('myModule').directive('ellipsis', [function () {
    return {
        required: 'ngBindHtml',
        restrict: 'A',
        priority: 100,
        link: function ($scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
            $scope.hasEllipsis = false;
            $scope.$watch(element.html(), function(value) {
               if (!$scope.hasEllipsis) {
                   // apply ellipsis only one
                   $scope.hasEllipsis = true;
                   element.ellipsis();
               }
            });
        }
    };
}]);
```

Your html is then:

```
<div class="item-content" ng-bind-html="item.text" ellipsis></div>
```

Of course, you need to include the jquery plugin in a `script` tag.

**EDIT**: I've edited the answer, so the directive will watch for the html to change (done by ngBindHtml).

Comment: Thank you, directive approach has worked. I needed to modify the directive a little bit (added $timeout to wait until binding is finished). Also I have updated question with working solution for this case. I'm accepting this as an answer since it has pointed me to correct direction. Thanks!

Comment: A pity for that $timeout service. I think the same could be achieved by watching the html content via `element.html()`.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to the accepted answer, this alternative allows improved customization: https://github.com/dibari/angular-ellipsis